# Python: Sort a list of strings composed of letters and numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list that its elements are composed of a letters and numbers as shown below :

```
['H1', 'H100', 'H10', 'H3', 'H2', 'H6', 'H11', 'H50', 'H5', 'H99', 'H8']
```

I wanted to sort it, so I used the function sort, but I got as output :

```
>>> a = ['H1', 'H100', 'H10', 'H3', 'H2', 'H6', 'H11', 'H50', 'H5', 'H99', 'H8']
>>> print sorted(a)
['H1', 'H10', 'H100', 'H11', 'H2', 'H3', 'H5', 'H50', 'H6', 'H8', 'H99']
```

However, I want the output to be :

```
['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H5', 'H6', 'H8', 'H10', 'H11', 'H50', 'H99', 'H100']
```

Does anyone has an idea how to do this please? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
l = ['H1', 'H100', 'H10', 'H3', 'H2', 'H6', 'H11', 'H50', 'H5', 'H99', 'H8']
print sorted(l, key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])))
```

**Output:**

```
['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H5', 'H6', 'H8', 'H10', 'H11', 'H50', 'H99', 'H100']
```

Comment: Thank you, a very simple and clear solution.

Comment: You are welcome :).

Comment: Hello @Rakesh, Could you please explain this part . `int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()]))` . Why `isdigit` is not giving false because i think it is working like this `isdigit('H1')` , `isdigit('H100')`....

Comment: @PIG This snippet gets the digit part of the string. For example 'H100' becomes 100. `for i in x if i.isdigit()` goes letter by letter and checks if the letter is digit or not. If it's digit it will add to the list. When we do `"".join` we then combine all elements of the list, that is the digits of a string together with empty separator, i.e. "".

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Thanks

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Which part of the code is removing character part from digit. For eg , expected should be `'H100'` , but which part of code giving input as `'100'` . . I am not understanding this part only.

Comment: @Rakesh My question is which part of coding is segregating `'H'` and `'101'` . Please explain.

Comment: @PIG. I am iterating over the string 'H100' and testing each element if it is a digit or not using the isdigit method if it is a digit I am concatenating them